# How to "un-capture" a captureStream() stream?

Tags: three.js, webrtc

To capture my ThreeJS scene into a movie I use:

```
stream = renderer.domElement.captureStream(25); // 25 FPS
```

and everything seems to work (the rest of the code is not important here).

My questions:

1. is it possible to stop capturing the stream? How?
2. if not and I leave the call to `captureStream()` in place even when I'm not capturing a movie, do this impacts on the ThreeJS performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`captureStream()` returns a `MediaStream` and you can call `track.stop()` on each of the `MediaStreamTracks`. This works like it does for camera but can not be as easily observed.

MDN has a [full sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop)